# Laravel migration error while adding foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

So I get this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1005 Can't create table `yamldb`.`#sql-3928_6ea` (errno: 150 "Foreign
>   key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `tblquestion`
>   add constraint `tblquestion_que_csd_id_foreign` foreign key
>   (`que_csd_id`) references `tblcsdomain` (`csd_id`))

### Table 1

```
Schema::create('tblquestion', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('que_id');
    $table->string('que_name', 128);
    $table->string('que_identifier', 128);
    $table->string('que_version', 50);
    $table->char('que_content');
    $table->char('que_answers');
    $table->integer('que_grd_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('que_quf_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('que_lan_id')->unsigned();
    $table->boolean('que_mandatory', false);
    $table->char('que_thisisinformatics');
    $table->char('que_translations');
    $table->char('que_explanation');
    $table->char('que_background_info');
    $table->integer('que_cou_id')->unsigned();
    $table->boolean('que_allow_share', false);
    $table->integer('que_source_cou_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('que_source_que_id');
    $table->mediumInteger('que_csd_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('que_token', 32);    
});
```

**Table 2**

```
Schema::create('tblcsdomain', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('csd_id');
    $table->string('csd_name', 128);
    $table->string('csd_token', 128);
 });
```

### Migration

```
 Schema::table('tblquestion', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('que_csd_id')->references('csd_id')->on('tblcsdomain');
}
```

Also I am trying to add FK to already existing columns. And Laravel adds the FK but on rollback it doesn't remove them.

```
Schema::table('tblquestion', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign(['que_csd_id']);
}
```

Comment: Is your foreign key on question table the same type as the id column on domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your foreign keys need to be the same type as your primary keys.

You either need to use

```
$table->mediumIncrements('csd_id');
```

In your Table 2 migration for the id column. Or change the type of

```
$table->mediumInteger('que_csd_id')->unsigned();
```

To

```
$table->integer('que_csd_id')->unsigned();
```

Answer (score 0):

The types of both columns are not the same.

`tblquestion.que_csd_id` is a medium integer.
`tblcsdomain.csd_id` is a normal integer.

You will have to change either one to the type of the other for this to work.